# Kafka Streams - filter data based on time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What is the easiest way to filter messages based on time. E.g. I receive following messages in kafka

```
1st second: 1 -> 23 (here 1 is key, 23 is value)
2nd second: 1 -> 445
3rd second: 1 -> 5
4th second: 1 -> 234
5th second: 1 -> 777
```

and if I need to forward 1 message per 2 seconds, I should have following filtered forward to some topic:

```
1 -> 23
1 -> 5
1 -> 777
```

It should also support dynamic window change - so in runtime someone could change window from 2 second to 10 seconds for example. What would be the best way to do this with Kafka streams?

**UPDATE**

Here is updated code that works for single events, but if it is batched, then the GlobalStore `lastSeen` is not updated. Seems like it actually updates this store via external push to kafka and then only it is received. Is it possible somehow to push timestamp to kafka, but to keep local in-memory state of `lastSeen` always synchronously updated?

```
KStream<String,String> input = streamsBuilder.stream("in", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        //here we store key -> when we saw last time this key
        GlobalKTable<String, Long> lastSeen = streamsBuilder.globalTable("ls", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
        //here we say key -> number of millis to skip the message
        GlobalKTable<String, Long> retentionPolicy = streamsBuilder.globalTable("rp", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

        record TempRec(String value, Long lastSeen, Long retentionPolicy){}

        KStream<String, TempRec> a = input
                .leftJoin(lastSeen, (k1,v1) -> k1, (v1,v2) -> new TempRec(v1, v2, null))
                .leftJoin(retentionPolicy, (k1,v1) -> k1, (v1,v2) -> new TempRec(v1.value(), v1.lastSeen(), v2))
                .filter((k,v) -> Instant.now().minusMillis(v.retentionPolicy()).isAfter(Instant.ofEpochMilli(v.lastSeen())));

        //HOW TO MAKE THIS ONE UPDATE SYNCHRONIZED??
        a.mapValues((k,v) -> Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
                .to("ls", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

        a.mapValues((k,v) -> v.value())
                .to("out");
```

Comment: If I understood the question, have you look at the punctuate method?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will check that one. I also updated the question with somewhat working example.